# Can't bind to 'car' since it isn't a known property of 'display'

Tags: angular

Same question was asked many times, however the suggestion provided didnot work for me.

Angular 5
error :

> Can't bind to 'car' since it isn't a known property of 'display'

Appmodule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  DisplayComponent,
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';
  car:Car = new Car();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.car.color = "black";
  }
}
```

app.html

```
hello world 
<display [car]='car'></display>
```

display.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css']
})
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() car : Car;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

display.html

```
<p>
  display works!
  car = {{ car.color }}
</p>
```

car object

```
export class Car {
    public color:String = "red";
}


Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 6.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.21
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.37
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.7
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Any help to fix the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The selector of the component doesn't match the element.

It should be

```
<app-display [car]='car'></app-display>
```

or

```
selector: 'display',
```

(instead of `selector: 'app-display',`)

Comment: thanks, changing to app-display works!!

However, my original project is having right tag, but still getting the above error

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-56fw6f

This model is working.  However, my original project is failing with bind error.

Can it be with migrating from version 2 to 5 issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. At least you know it's not your code.